# How to update a datetime column milliseconds in SQL time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, timestamp, ssms

I have a `datetime` column in SQL Server 2014. I am using SSMS 2018 client. I want to update the value of one of the timestamp from

```
2017-01-06 06:32:23.197
```

to

```
2017-01-06 06:32:23.196
```

I used the following, but it doesn't change the time, but unfortunately shows as "1 row affected". How can it be possible? It shows same milliseconds

Just 0.001 millisecond less, how to do?

```
update Process
set Date = '2017-01-06 06:32:23.197'
where ID = '33'
```

Comment: @DaleK: Sorry it is not duplicate, the issue you referred is different to this. I am trying to "Update a VALUE"

Comment: @DaleK: I found the answer, cheers

Comment: You'll need to use `DATETIME2(3)` datatype if you want millisecond precision - `DATETIME` is accurate to only 3.33ms -......